# rPlay on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: pi-3, shairplay

I successfully installed and launched rPlay 1.0.1 on Raspberry Pi 3. The network connection is now via WiFi (no LAN cables plugged in).

However, in order to get the AirPlay working, do I have to plug in the LAN cable, and stop the device from connecting to WiFi?

p.s. AFAIK, AirPlay communicates via WiFi. Does rPlay create its own WiFi hotspot?

Comment: rPlay is dead. It is closed source and has not been updated for 5 years. Too bad for all of us.

Comment: so it does not work anymore? recently Apple released AirPlay API to vendors, will that affect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an Lightning-to-Ethernet-Adapter you can use AirPlay purely over Ethernet as well. ;)
Both devices can be connected anyway they like but they have to be in the same network. I personally use `shairport-sync` as it is a better maintained project. But it supports audio only.

The new AirPlay 2 API might change things if someone implements a solution for that. As other vendors are more leaky than Apple, there might be a chance.

Comment: AirPlay via Ethernet? how? I got the adapter, but not sure how I can make use of that.

Comment: This is not really useful but you will need something like [that](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/3-in-1-Charger-Adapter-For-Lightning-to-LAN-100Mbps-Ethernet-RJ45-Adapter-OTG-USB-3/32970173268.html).

Comment: Just connect your iDevice and your AirPlay client to your router and then it will work. A wireless solution at least on your iDevices end will be more practical anyway.

Comment: I never thought this will work!